# How to paste text from clipboard to the cygwin shell in VirtualBox VM running on OSX?

Tags: macos, virtualbox, cygwin

I have installed a copy of cygwin in a Windows Server 2012 which is hosted in a VirtualBox VM.

The new cygwin terminal is not a simple DOS prompt anymore. From the option I will need to use `Ctrl/Shift-Ins` to paste text into the shell.

[image]

However my VirtualBox is running on OSX macbookpro. There is no 'INS' key on the keyboard. How can I work around this?

Answer (score 2):

This has been driving me absolutely bonkers. The suggestions to re-map paste-from-clipboard to Control-V in ~/.inputrc found [here](http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/05/how-to-paste-in-cygwin-bash-using-ctrl/) didn't work for me.

BUT, there is hope if you have a Mac keyboard with the numeric pad. It turns out the numpad '0' is mapped to INSERT. So, in cygwin you can simply copy with

> Ctrl + 0

and paste like

> Shift + 0

This works for me running cygwin within Windows 7 using Bootcamp. If you have a newer Macbook with no numpad shortcut (e.g fn + m) you can try re-mapping the keyboard within Windows. Here's one program that might do the trick: http://sharpkeys.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

Copy - select text, press control key, click on mousepad, select copy from dropdown menu.

Paste - set text cursor where you want to paste, press control, click on mousepad, select paste from dropdown menu.